# Custom hyphenation for a different language

Tags: babel, hyphenation

I load `babel` and specify the default language, but adding words of that language to `\hyphenation{}` command results in a number of errors:

> Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. \hyphenation{в
>
> Not a letter. \hyphenation{в

and lots more. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}
\hyphenation{в-т}
\begin{document}
вт
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, use `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}`. It will at least compile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. With `\hyphenation{прев-ысокомногорассмотрительст-вующий}` we are saying that "превысокомногорассмотрительствующий" can be split at either "в-ы" or т-в".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}

\hyphenation{прев-ысокомногорассмотрительст-вующий}

\begin{document}
превысокомногорассмотрительствующий превысокомногорассмотрительствующий
Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, не вим иудицо фацете перпетуа. Ид вис фугит салутатус форенсибус. превысокомногорассмотрительствующий
Нец еа еверти дицерет нумяуам. Нец ут мазим аццусамус цонцлусионемяуе, сед еи инермис детрахит превысокомногорассмотрительствующий. превысокомногорассмотрительствующий Долоре нолуиссе диссентиас ан сеа, ад сит цонсул пертинациа репримияуе. превысокомногорассмотрительствующий Про еа иудицо муциус иудицабит, пер новум молестие перицулис ин превысокомногорассмотрительствующий.
\end{document}
```

[image]